# How to store menu font icons in sitecore

Tags: html, css, svg, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I've a sitecore solution where all menu navigation items are managed via sitecore. All good if we use png, jpg etc.

Now the FE guys wants to use the Fonts icons so that it's responsive and works on any browser devices.

One way to overcome this is by creating a class field in menu item where authors will specify the icon-class.

Problem with this is that authors will need to understand css classes and everytime new items needs to be created, they need to involve developers.

Is there a better way to overcome this? Or using png/svg images are best option.

Comment: What about to add a "icon picker" like this? http://mjolnic.com/fontawesome-iconpicker/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently created a font icon picker field for Sitecore that sounds like it would meet your requirements. Authors can choose from one or more "collections", such as FontAwesome, IcoMoon, Foundation, etc., so they don't need to have knowledge of the CSS class names.

The field accepts configuration via JSON in the field's 'source'. Within the configuration, you can point to one or more CSS files that contain the icon classes, as well as control which ones are displayed (via regex). In other words, you do not need to define each and every CSS class, it will parse your CSS file(s) and display them automatically.

[More Information](http://www.layerworks.com/blog/2015/8/26/icon-font-picker-custom-field)

[Download Market Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/F/Font_Icon_Picker_Field.aspx)

[image: Sitecore Font Icon Picker Field]

Comment: Thank you looks good. Read your blog. I'm newbie to font icons.  How do you display the icons on choose icon gallery? i.e. do we need to upload the icon or css or json so that it only shows icons that can be used.

Comment: And if we need to add new menu items what does author and developer needs to do?

Comment: @Myagdi, you need to reference the CSS file that contains the icon fonts in the field's JSON configuration. You can simply reference your site's minified 'bundle', as long as it contains the font icon classes. When new icons are added, the field will pick them up automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a project and created a custom Sitecore field to provide a searchable UI for the users to pick icons from.

[image: SPEAK UI interface]

The field also provides a preview of the selected icon on the item for the user.

[image: Icon Preview]

Its available as a module on the Sitecore Marketplace here [Icon Selector Field](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/I/Icon_Selector_Field.aspx?sc_lang=en)

Comment: Thanks. How does it actually works. From what I understand the font icon actually doesn't exist as individual file? What do we need to upload to sitecore so that it can be selected from this new field? Also how does ICON maps to css icon classes?

Comment: The only thing you need in Sitecore is a item mapping the CssClass you wish to surface for the user, ie icon-arrow-bottom by default here - /sitecore/content/Jet2 Flights/Site Content/Custom Icons, this is then picked up by the custom field and your css to the following file - sitecore\shell\client\Your Apps\Dialogs\InsertCustomIconDialog\Icons.css

Answer (score 0):

You can write C# code that read all the font classes from the css font file, then save these classes into Sitcore items.

The Sitecore Items that you save will contain the class name in it's field.

Use this code to load the classes names :
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3120/loading-css-class-names-in-csharp

Then change the datasource of the navigation items to the CSS classes items that you saved.